# C# Winforms DataGridView bold font style in rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Why there is no text in rows?
How to make text in rows bold?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn { HeaderText = "Test", CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell() { }, DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle { Font = new Font("Tahoma", 9.75F, FontStyle.Bold) } });
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = new List<Employee> 
            { 
                 new Employee {Name="Test"},
                 new Employee {Name="Test"},
                 new Employee {Name="Test"},
                 new Employee {Name="Test"},
                 new Employee {Name="Test"},
                 new Employee {Name="Test"},
                 new Employee {Name="Test"}
            };
        }
    }
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the [`DataPropertyName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property for your column.

> Gets or sets the name of the data source property or database column to which the DataGridViewColumn is bound.

Change it to this:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn { 
    HeaderText = "Test", 
    DataPropertyName = "Name", 
    CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell() { }, 
    DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle { Font = new Font("Tahoma", 9.75F, FontStyle.Bold), ForeColor = Color.Black } 
});
```

That should add the rows with bolded font.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingList<Employee> list = new BindingList<Employee>();
    list.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Test1" });
    list.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Test2" });
    list.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Test3" });
    list.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Test4" });
    list.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Test5" });

    dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
}
```